# KSQL query adds too much delay to my request

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a system that saves (X,Y) coordinates to a SQL table. Then, I have an endpoint that when called returns the (X,Y) coordinates.

However my system takes up to 30 minutes to process and store a (X,Y) coordinate to the SQL table. In this sense, I am using KSQL to get that data faster.

I have added the call to KSQL in the endpoint of the backend I mentioned. The problem is that this call adds 6 extra seconds to my request.

My endpoint includes a query that looks like this

`SELECT feature_a,feature_b FROM ksql_table;`

The ksql_table has already been pre-processed by two previous streams. In my understanding, this query should be pretty straight forward and easy to compute. But it is taking 6 seconds to process.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail? Are you talking about building a UDF?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I have updated the question. Thanks. I am not building a UDF. It is a real time location software. I cannot change anything in the sink from kafka to the database. I can only work on getting the latest data as messages arrive at kafka.

Comment: ah, so you're using the KSQL REST API to query the state from the table? What's your application written in? If it's JVM then I think Kafka Streams would be more appropriate here.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is written in nodejs. I just found out what was the problem. The developer is setting a threshold of incoming messages which of course adds delay to the promise. I think it would be better to stream the query to the frontend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a KSQL query runs, it instantiates a Kafka Streams application that will build the table state requested. This is going to have a "spin-up" time, which doesn't matter when it's the stream processing application itself (since once it's running it stays running). However, if you're repeatedly calling it via the REST API as part of your application's flow then you are going to see this delay.

I think a more optimal way to work with the stream of data in Kafka would be to use Kafka Streams to build and persist the state required in a KTable, and then serve this through [Interactive Query](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html) and a custom API that your nodejs application can interface with such as described [here](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/03/interactive-queries-in-apache-kafka-streams/). Further examples are [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.1.0-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/interactivequeries/kafkamusic/KafkaMusicExample.java) and [here](https://medium.com/@abhishek1987/kafka-streams-interactive-queries-9a05ff92d75a).

There is also a [nodejs Kafka Streams library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-streams), which I have not used but might be worth checking out.